# JLabel.setBackground(Color.RED); Is Not Working

Tags: java, swing, colors, background, jlabel

As you can see from the title, I can't set a background color of a `JLabel`.
Can someone please help?

```java
package pl.maciekfruba;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Message");
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        JLabel l = new JLabel("Some text");
        BorderLayout bl = new BorderLayout();
        Font font = new Font("Impact", Font.PLAIN, 30);
        l.setBackground(Color.RED);
        l.setFont(font);
        l.setOpaque(true);
        p.add(l);
        f.add(p, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        f.setLayout(bl);
        f.setSize(new Dimension(1000, 600));
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I tried calling method `setOpaque(true)` but it still is not working.

Comment: Your code needs reformatting and as posted, won't compile. 
Don't reset the layout, the default is *already* `BorderLayout`, which is overwritten by your setting it. So remove any line of code with `bl` in it

Comment: The JFrame's contentPane's layout is already border layout, so no need to change it. Also, perhaps it's not best to change a container's layout *after* adding components to it.

Comment: as @HovercraftFullOfEels mentioned the issue is the order of method call so remove f.setLayout(bl); or put it before you add component to f and you need to set the action when you close the window by f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

Answer (score 1):

Best also to start GUIs from the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) (EDT) so:

```
package pl.maciekfruba;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Main extends JFrame {
    private void setGui() {
        try {
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            JPanel p = new JPanel();
            JLabel l = new JLabel("Some text");
            Font font = new Font("Impact", Font.PLAIN, 30);
            l.setBackground(Color.RED);
            l.setFont(font);
            l.setOpaque(true);
            p.add(l);
            add(p, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            EventQueue.invokeAndWait(() -> {
                Main f = new Main();
                f.setGui();
                f.setSize(1000, 1000);
                f.setVisible(true);
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```